# Is each TS-topologizable group TG-topologizable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids

**Definition 1.** A topology $\tau$ on a group $X$ is called

$\bullet$ a *semigroup topology* if the multiplication $X\times X\to X$, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$, is continuous in the topology $\tau$;

$\bullet$ a *group topology* if the multiplication $X\times X\to X$, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$, and the inversion $X\to X$, $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, are continuous in the topology $\tau$.

**Definition 2.** A group $X$ is called

$\bullet$ *$TS$-topologizable* if $X$ admits a nondiscrete Hausdorff semigroup topology;

$\bullet$ *$TG$-topologizable* if $X$ admits a nondiscrete Hausdorff group topology.

Since each group topology is a semigroup topology, any $TG$-topologizable group is $TS$-topologizable.

What about the converse?

> **Problem** (Bardyla): *Is any $TS$-topologizable group $TG$-topologizable?*